# Most concise way to parse a three-digit number in Haskell (Trifecta)

Tags: parsing, haskell, refactoring, trifecta

What is the idiomatic way parse three consecutive digits into a string?

The following works, but does not scale:

```
threeDigits :: Parser Int
threeDigits = do
    d1 <- digit
    d2 <- digit
    d3 <- digit
    return (digitToInt d1 * 100 + digitToInt d2 * 10 + digitToInt d3)
```

More generally, how can this scale for N numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`count`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#v:count).

```
digits :: Int -> Parser Int
digits n = read <$> count n digit
```

Comment: Is your `Parser` type a synonym of `ReadP`?

Comment: Also known as `replicateM :: Applicative m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`.

Comment: @4castle it is a `Text.Trifecta.Parser`; I've updated the question. If I understand correctly, it is not related to `ReadP`, but has a very similar API. Since `count` comes from `Applicative`, I believe the same approach should work with `ReadP`.